# How to iterate over one nested list, compare specific elements for a match, create a dictionary with specific different elements based on the match?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, nested-lists

I am very new to Python and was looking for help: I have ONE nested list:

`[['t', '=', 'a', '+1', 'b'], ['s', '=', 'd', '+2', 'e'], ['p', '=', 't', '*1', 'c'], ['q', '=', 's', '/1', 'f'], ['y', '=', 'p', '-1', 'q']]`.

I want to compare to find a match for every 1st element of each sub-list with all the 3rd and 5th elements of all sublists. For example: `'t'` as the 1st element in the 1st sublist compared with `'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 't', 'c', 's', 'f', 'p', 'q'` (3rd and 5th elements of each sublist) to find a potential match in the elements. Then I compare `'s'` (1st element of 2nd sublist) with the 3rd and 5th elements of all sublists. I repeat this until I have compared all 1st elements of each sublist with every 3rd and 5th elements of all sublists.

After that, wherever I find a match (for example, `'t'` as 1st element in 1st sublist is found as the 3rd element in the 3rd sublist, etc.), I would like to connect the 4th elements (operators) of those 2 sublists together as a dictionary to represent the nodes of a graph. For example, for the match found for `'t'` in sublists 1 and 3, operator `+1` (4th element in sublist 1) would be "key" and operator `*1` (4th element in sublist 3) would be the corresponding "value" of the dictionary. Similarly, for match found for `'s'`, `'+2'` and `'/1'` would be key-value pairs, for match found for `'p'`, `'*1'` and `'-1'` would connect, and so on until all 1st-element sublists are compared to find matches.

I have tried the following but it is returning an empty list [] as the output:

`op_connector1 = []`  #I created an empty list for now to collect all the desired operators for the nodes of the graph, but would eventually like a dictionary, like I stated above.

`list = [['t', '=', 'a', '+1', 'b'], ['s', '=', 'd', '+2', 'e'], ['p', '=', 't', '*1', 'c'], ['q', '=', 's', '/1', 'f'], ['y', '=', 'p', '-1', 'q']]`

`for i in range(len(list)):`

```
if (list[i][0] == list[i][2]) or (list[i][0] == list[i][4]):
    op_connector1.append(i[i][3])
print("\n", op_connector1)
```

Desired Output:

`{'+1': '*1', '+2': '/1', '*1': '-1', '/1': '-1'}`

Would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output? Please edit your post to contain this information. Concretely write it out; do not just provide a high-level description.

Answer (score 0):

try that one

```
super_arr=[
    ['t', '=', 'a', '+1', 'b'],
    ['s', '=', 'd', '+2', 'e'], 
    ['p', '=', 't', '*1', 'c'], 
    ['q', '=', 's', '/1', 'f'],
    ['y', '=', 'p', '-1', 'q']
    ]
def compare_list(super_array):
    dict={}
    for array in super_array:
        
        for each_list in super_array:
            if array[0] in (each_list[2],each_list[4]):
                dict[array[3]]=each_list[3]
            
    return dict
 #calling the function and printing its output
               
print(compare_list(super_arr))
    

output:


    {'+1': '*1', '+2': '/1', '*1': '-1', '/1': '-1'}
```

alternatively,

```
super_arr=[
    ['t', '=', 'a', '+1', 'b'],
    ['s', '=', 'd', '+2', 'e'], 
    ['p', '=', 't', '*1', 'c'], 
    ['q', '=', 's', '/1', 'f'],
    ['y', '=', 'p', '-1', 'q']
    ]
def compare_list(super_array):
    dict={}
    for array in super_array:
        subdict={}
        
        for each_list in super_array:
            if array[0] in (each_list[2],each_list[4]):
                subdict[array[3]]=each_list[3]
        dict[array[0]]=subdict
    return dict
 #calling the function and printing its output                
print(compare_list(super_arr))
    

Output:
{'t': {'+1': '*1'}, 's': {'+2': '/1'}, 'p': {'*1': '-1'}, 'q': {'/1': '-1'}, 'y': {}}
```

using list comprehensions the function can be written as

```
def compare_list(super_array):
    dict={}
    for array in super_array:
        x={array[3]:each_list[3] for each_list in super_array if array[0] in (each_list[2],each_list[4])}
        dict[array[0]]=x
    return dict
```

For duplicated keys you can use the following function

```
def compare_list(super_array):
    list_of_dicts=[]
    for array in super_array:
        subdict={}
        
        for each_list in super_array:
            if array[0] in (each_list[2],each_list[4]):
                subdict[array[3]]=each_list[3]
                list_of_dicts.append(f'{array[0]}:{subdict}')
        # dict[array[0]]=subdict
    return list_of_dicts

output:
["t:{'+1': '+2'}", "t:{'+1': '*1'}", "s:{'+2': '/1'}", "p:{'*1': '-1'}", "q:{'/1': '-1'}"]
```

Comment: Instead of using two lists, you can combine them, ```if array[0] in (each_list[2], each_list[4])```

Comment: Also, in your nested for loop, you don't need to start iteration from beginning, instead you can just start from current index + 1.

Comment: ooh yes i had to combine .how did i miss that part....!!!!    For the second comment i was just considering if it happens a match is found in previous list,i would miss it by starting from index+1.ie. if the list provided is  ['t', '=', 'p', '+1', 'b'], ['s', '=', 'q', '+2', 'e'], ['p', '=', 't', '*1', 'c'], ['q', '=', 's', '/1', 'f'],['y', '=', 'a', '-1', 'd']
    ]

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: sure. Best wishes

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working!
However, say if I have the following nested list:
[ ['t', '=', 'a', '+1', 'b'], ['s', '=', 't', '+2', 'e'], ['p', '=', 't', '*1', 'c'], ['q', '=', 's', '/1', 'f'], ['y', '=', 'p', '-1', 'q'] ], for the first element 't' in the first sub-list, I now have two matches (3rd element in the 2nd sublist and 3rd element in the 3rd sublist). The program is only considering the 3rd element in the 3rd sublist and pairing +1 with *1, in place of making +1 as key and +2 and *1 as the corresponding dictionary values. Thinking about multiple matches for each of t, s, etc.

Comment: this is because the key 't' is duplicated and hence it is replaced by the second match.If the output is not limited to being dict the function can return a list of string

Comment: Thanks you so much, Dante! Appreciate all your help and hard work!